# iOS 10 - View Controller / Navigation Bar Title hidden

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar, pushviewcontroller, titlebar

I'm currently facing stranges behaviours with **iOS 10**.

Indeed, everything was working fine, but since I updated to **xCode 8** and began testing my App on **iOS 10**, a lot of stuff went wrong.

For example, all my *Navigation Bar*'s *titles* are not displayed anymore.

More precisely, when I'm using the menu to navigate threw my app, every time I switch to a different view, there are no title, BUT when I press the back button, I can briefly see it before the transition to the other view.
I don't understand this new behaviour, I didn't change anything in the code, and when I launch the App on iOS 9 or lesser, everything is working properly.

I tried to set the title in the *ViewWillAppear* / *ViewDidLoad*, in the *prepareForSegue*, but nothing is working.

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:kMy_Segue]) {
    MyViewController* destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    [destinationVC setTitle:@"MyTitle"];
}
```

I feel like there are some changes with the pushed Navigation Controller, or the title item is not at the same index than the Navigation Bar itself because when I navigate threw subviews in the menu, the title only appears when I press back.

For example I have a category in my Menu called **"World"**.
When I tap it I want the title of the subview to be **"World"**, but nothing is displayed. Then, I have all the continents listed **"Africa"**, **"Europe"**, **"Asia"** etc...
When I tap on **Africa**, I want the next title to be **"Africa"** right?
And again, nothing is displayed BUT if I press the back button and go back to the list of continents, the title **"World"** appears.

If anyone has encountered this issue, I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: please check my solution and reply. If neccessay i will add a sample project..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this:

### Solution-1

Goto to the viewController, then click on NavigationItem as shown below:

[image]

In the right pane, change "Title" as follows:

[image]

### Solution-2

Add a UIView to your navigationBar as shown below:

[image]

Add an UILabel to your navigationItem as shown below:

[image]

Change the frame of the newly added UILabel as follows:

[image]

Change text of UILabel to "Sample Title" and change UIView backgroundColor to clearColor.

I have made a sample in Xcode8, please check my GitHub link below:

https://github.com/k-sathireddy/NavigationItemSample

Comment: Even if it's a great idea, it's not working, the titles aren't showing...
I don't understand what's wrong with my navigation controller.

Comment: Shall i add a sample to test?

Comment: I'm testing your second solution.

Comment: I did like you said. I tried on the simplest view controller, not working...
Even if the title is displayed in the storyboard, when I launch the app, the Nav Bar is empty. No title, and no title for the back icon too.

Comment: But I can see them when I press the back button, during the transition of the 2 Views.

Comment: Ok your sample is working perfectly, I'll take a loot at my implementation.
I'll keep you informed about my progress.

Comment: Are there any changes on the Localizable.strings since iOS 10?

Comment: I think no effect of Localizable.strings on navigation bar.

Comment: Another solution: Add a UILabel to view on top of navigationBar in storyboard..it will definitely work..

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to adding navigation item on to your navigation bar? You'r using Storyboard for this design.

Comment: I tried with self.navigationItem.title = @"YourTitle" and self.title = @"Some Title"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue. It's really weird.

I have a fade animation to the navigation bar on the Home Page. 
It's a scroll view so that when I scroll down I can still see the title and the navigation bar.

On iOS < 10, the fade animation only change the background color and transparency. But when I launch the app on iOS 10, the fade effect hide everything, the menu icon, the title, everything. I believe Apple changed the structure of the navigation bar items.

Moreover, when I tap on the menu icon to navigate threw my App when the fade animation is on going, I can see that the title and the navigation bar items are under "fade effect" and even for the next ViewControllers's title after my navigation.

So it's working, it's just that the menu icon, titles etc.. are hidden on the Navigation Bar.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    UIColor * color = [Constants backgroundColor];
    CGFloat offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat threshold = 250;
    if (offsetY > threshold) {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar lt_setBackgroundColor:[color colorWithAlphaComponent:1]];
    } else {
        CGFloat alpha =  offsetY / threshold;
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar lt_setBackgroundColor:[color colorWithAlphaComponent:alpha]];
    }
}
```

I guess the issue is coming from the library LTNavigationBar that I used to change the appearance of the NavigationBar dynamically...